# Unable to map the logstash with ElasticSearch on linux

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Unable to map the logstash with ElasticSearch on linux

I just run the below command and it shows all the running images on docker

**sudo docker ps**

**Output:**

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE             COMMAND                   CREATED           STATUS           PORTS                    NAMES
e14ace6bd419    a962b6541416      "/bin/bash /usr/loca…"    23 hours ago      Up 22 hours      0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp   trusting_chatterjee
00e6822bb991    28259852697e      "/usr/local/bin/dock…"    23 hours ago      Up 23 hours      9200/tcp, 9300/tcp       friendly_roentgen
```

I just want to link the logstash into elastic search and tried to run the below command

**Command:**

```sh
 sudo docker run -d --rm -it -v /home/sabharanikumar/logstash.conf e95781358676
```

**Output:**

989e2a8f4d9fd972c4f2102d726a68877c989b546800899abbb8c382fb62f04c

**logstash.conf:**

```
input
{
  stdin{}
}
output
{
  elasticsearch{ hosts => ["localhost:9200"] } 
}
```

**Logstash Log:**

> [2019-08-23T09:40:53,833][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
>   Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an
>   error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/",
>   :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError,
>   :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable:
>   [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure]
>   elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}

I ran the **sudo docker ps** but the logstash is being listed.

Is there anything I missed it? Is there anywhere I need to change the host value?

Comment: You need to run `sudo docker ps -a` and then you will see your container with an Exit status. Run `docker logs <container_name>` and post the result if you still need help with figuring it out, but most probably the log will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Also "localhost:9200" doesn't look right. This configuration is read inside a container. For that container localhost is the container itself. I think you want to point to `friendly_roentgen` instead. Regarding the container names, I suggest you give them names when you start them instead of letting docker choose another random name each time you start your containers.

Comment: Updated with latest finds. I just updated the command and observed that logstash is being up and running now. but still it throws some error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mihai pointed out in the comments, "localhost:9200" is not correct. The logstash container will try to communicate with itself on the port 9200 but nothing is listening on there.

The second problem I see is that you're passing the logstash configuration file as parameter (or command) to docker. Moreover you should avoid using the `--link` option since it's deprecated and prefer the network generation.

In other words, the commands should look like this:

```
docker network create \
    --driver bridge \
    --subnet=172.100.0.0/16 \
    --gateway=172.100.0.1 \
    my_elk_net
```

and then starting both the docker containers using the `--network=my_elk_net` option. e.g.

```
docker run -d \
    --name elasticsearch \
    --name my_elk_net \
    <ElasticSearchIMAGEID>

docker run -d \
    --name logstash \
    --network my_elk_net \
    -v "/home/arrchana/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro"
    <LogstashIMAGEID>
```

Your elastic search should look like this now:

```
input
{
  stdin{}
}
output
{
  elasticsearch{ hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] } 
}
```

In alternative, you can use docker-compose and avoid the creation of the network.
A very basic example of a docker-compose.yml, that should work for you, should look like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: image_image

  logstash:
    image: logstash_image
    volumes:
      - /home/arrchana/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
    depends_on:
     - elasticsearch
```

Comment: This makes life easy.. Thanks you

Comment: no problem, I'm afraid that with the current setup you're going to face some other issues concerning the `stdin {}` in docker but TBH I'm not sure at all.